# python. function called inside a recurrent function only runs once then the remainder of function repeats

Tags: python, repeat, gpio

I am extremely new to python and trying to control gpio pins on raspberry pi to flash multiple lights.

Tried to set up a function to control each light separately. then another function which allows them to blink.

when i set the "color" function as a variable in the "blink" function. The light only flashes once and then the rest of the repeat function, continues until the repeat is finished. Why doesn't it repeat the "color" function each time it repeats.

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO Library
import time ## Import 'time' library.  Allows us to use 'sleep'
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use BOARD pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO pin 7 to OUT
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

## Prompt user for input
iterations = raw_input("Enter the total number of times to blink: ")
speed = raw_input("Enter the length of each blink in seconds: ")

## Define function named Blink()
def green(speed):
  print "green on"
  GPIO.output(7, True) ## Turn on GPIO pin 7
  time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
  print "green off"
  GPIO.output(7, False) ## Switch off GPIO pin 7
  time.sleep(speed) ## Wait

def red(speed):
    print "red on"
    GPIO.output(11, True) ## Turn on GPIO pin 7
    time.sleep(speed) ## Wait
    print "red off"
    GPIO.output(11, False) ## Switch off GPIO pin 7
    time.sleep(speed) ## Wait

def Blink(numTimes,color):
    while numTimes > 0:
        print "Iteration " + str(numTimes) ##Print current loop
        color
        numTimes = numTimes - 1


## Start Blink() function. 

Blink(int(iterations),green(float(speed)))
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: did you mean to do `color()` inside the function `Blink()`?

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that when you pass `green(float(speed))` as an argument, that expression is evaluated (i.e. `green` is called), and the result -- which in this case is `None` -- is passed into `Blink`. Thus, `green` is only called once.

The expression `color` that you have inside `Blink` is effectively a no-op.

One way you can do what you're trying to do is as follows:

```
def Blink(numTimes, color, speed):
#                          ↑↑↑↑↑ Add a third argument
    while numTimes > 0:
        print "Iteration " + str(numTimes)
        color(speed)
        #    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ Call the function (with the right argument)
        numTimes = numTimes - 1


## Start Blink() function. 

Blink(int(iterations), green, float(speed))
#                      ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ pass the name of the function and the speed
```

Comment: I would have added that the result of the function is `None` since there is no return statement, but otherwise +1 as this is what I was typing up as well.